# Unable to load OData adapter from assembly Simple.OData.Client.V3.Adapter

Tags: c#, xamarin, odata

I have the following code which I expect to get oData (`Simple.oData.Client`) from `Northwind` service. Once user clicks on the Click button, then it triggers the oData Call. It prints out `before await` message on the console;however, it does not print `after await` message. It means there is something not going right in await operation in the `try-catch` block. I would like to know how to handle that problem. 
I am using Xamarin.iOS platform.

```
async partial  void Click_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        var client= new ODataClient("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");

        Console.WriteLine("before await");

        try {
        var packages = await client
            .For("Customers").
            FindEntriesAsync();
        }
        catch(AggregateException e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
        }
    Console.WriteLine("after await");
   }
```

Here is the detail error message:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load OData adapter from
>   assembly Simple.OData.Client.V3.Adapter --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Simple.OData.Client.V3.Adapter' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: where are you getting Simple.oData.Client from - Nuget, Component Store, or somewhere else?

Comment: @Jason,  I have got it from Nuget. Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To whom need to know how this issue has been resolved, here is the detail explanation from the source code owner of the `Simple.OData.Client` github.

https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/53

I have added a single line of code `Simple.OData.Client.V3Adapter.Reference()` in my `Main.cs`, and it works like a charm.

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Simple.OData.Client.V3Adapter.Reference();
    UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get the error I am using V4Adapter

Comment: Thanks this helped me, Although I added V4Adapter.Reference() instead, but it resolved this issue for me.

Comment: I removed from nuget the simple.odata package and reinstalled.

Answer (score 2):

Having lost most of the week to this one. I thought I'd share my slightly different resolution.

I've been upgrading a `netcoreapp3.1` to `net7`

Despite there being not compile time time errors, I was missing the `Microsoft.OData.Core` NuGet pkg. No references to it in the code anywhere, but adding this to the offending projects resolved my error

`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load OData adapter from assembly Simple.OData.Client.V4.Adapter`